# Can I omit the relative pronoun and the verb 'be' in the this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, relative-pronouns, free-relative-clauses, relative-clauses

Can I omit the relative pronoun and the verb 'be' in the this sentence? That is, can:

> I doubt we presume too far in thinking that by scientific truthfulness, he means proven facts **which are** not prone to change.

be changed to:

> I doubt we presume too far in thinking that by scientific truthfulness, he means proven facts **not prone to change**.

Comment: Either version looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can. Both are good English. The second sentence is, however, a bit more vague in meaning, and would only be worthwhile in formal situations. When you speak normally, you wouldn't omit the relative pronoun.